# Can't return the correct int in C

Tags: c, quicksort

i'm using this function (quicksort algorithm) and im
trying to get the total relocations also. In order to collect as much statitics i can i have to execute the function many times using a for loop, so after the end of the algorithm i must make the static variable equal to zero after copying it to a non-static variable and return it. Instead i always get a 0 return.
Please help me to not get a 0 grade too :P Thanks

```
int quicksort(int left, int right, int *p)
{
    static int staticrelocations=0;
    int i,j,mid,x,temp,relocations;

    if(left<right)
    {
        i=left;
        j=right;
        mid=(left+right)/2;
        x=p[mid];
        while(i<j)
        {
            while(p[i]<x)
                i++;
            while(p[j]>x)
                j--;
            if(i<j)
            {
                if(p[i]==p[j])
                {
                    if(i<mid)
                        i++;
                    if(j>mid)
                        j--;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp=p[i];
                    p[i]=p[j];
                    p[j]=temp;
                    staticrelocations++;
                }
            }
        }
        quicksort(left,j-1,p);
        quicksort(j+1,right,p);
    }
    relocations=staticrelocations;
    staticrelocations=0;
    return relocations;
}
```

Comment: I get the feeling you don't understand what was being asked of you because there's no sense in setting the static value to 0 at the end of the function and copying it to another variable and returning it that way, because as you also set the static variable to zero in the beginning.  And whether you return a value via a static variable, non static, or literal makes no difference.  If you want a static variable to persist beyond the length of the function declare it outside the function, or if you declare it in the function you have to be selective and clever about how you initialize it.

Comment: As for why staticrelocations is zero as a result of your sort algorithm processing, no one could know that without seeing your input data. If you provide the input data *maybe* someone will take the time to help.  But don't provide too much data, find a good small example, and be sure to format it clearly to make it very readable, and accurate.

Comment: I just want a static variable to persist only in the algorithm part, because it is a recursion function. If i return the static variable instead, all relocations will be added to the previous records.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, you are returning the same value you have in the static variable. I doesn't matter that you copied it to another variable and return that instead, because what you are returning is the *value* contained *in* the variable, not the variable itself or a pointer to it.

Comment: Oh.. i feel so bad, i didn't know that the whole function is executed after the algorithms recursion. I'll try to fix the code.

Comment: a little more study on using recursion is needed.  However the main problem is the counts are being lost.  suggest eliminate that static variable.  suggest summing the returned counts from each recursive call into a local variable. (you get a new local variable on each recursion)  so if each call to quicksort() returns the current local variable value and the returned values are always summed into the (then) current local variable, then the final return to main will return the correct value.  otherwise there will be problems similar/like the one you are currently seeing

Comment: @RoastedCode Don't worry or be embarrassed. You're new at this and said you are, and this stuff can be tough to learn and confusing at first. You'll master it.

Comment: Thanks for you help and for the good words :) I'll try my best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You recurse into `quicksort()`, and in the innermost invocation you set `staticrelocations = 0` before returning its former value. However, in the outer `quicksort()`, you *ignore* the return value of the inner `quicksort`. The outer quicksort returns the zeroed `staticrelocations`. Instead, you should go like this:

```
int quicksort()
{
  int relocs = 0;
  /* function logic */
  if (/*did a new relocation*/)
    relocs++;
  relocs += quicksort(); //inner quicksort recursively
  return relocs;
}
```